# How fill height for a child in Row in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a row with 2 children; an image and a column.
I want image height equals its parent but I cant do that and I read related questions and solutions but I cant use `IntrinsicSize.Max`

I want the single image fills the max height.

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun Images(
    firstImageId: Int,
    secondImageId: Int,
    thirdImageId: Int,
) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = firstImageId),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .weight(1f)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = secondImageId),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(4 / 3f)
            )
         
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = thirdImageId),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(4 / 3f)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use a `Box`, you can use `Modifier.matchParentSize()`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jorn, Thank you for your answer, but I am not using box, Can you help me with aspectRatio or another idea?

Comment: Please try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76596456/21100774