# How to match parent height of a Card in Column in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a linear layout like view in jetpack compose, only issue is that match parent is not working as expected.

[image: The thing I Desire]

I want the other cards to fill the entire space

Here is my code

```
    fun RowOne(mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel) {
        val circleSize = 120.dp
        val strokeWidth = 2.dp
        Row {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(5.dp)
                    .weight(1F),
                elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(4.dp)
            ) {
                Column {
                    TextSubHeader("Battery Percentage")
                    circularBatteryBar(circleSize, mainActivityViewModel, strokeWidth)
                }
            }
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(5.dp)
                    .weight(1F),
                elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(4.dp)
            ) {
                TextSubHeader("Battery Health")
            }
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1F)
                    .padding(5.dp), text = "AAAAA", textAlign = TextAlign.Center, maxLines = 1
            )
        }
    }
```

what I tried and didn't work -> `.weight, .fillMaxHeight(), .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)`

I am really getting tired of the issues in jetpack compose. can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried height(IntrinsicSize.Min) without the fillmaxheight modifier ?

Comment: Yes tried this combination too, if possible can you try to replicate this code on your side and let me know for a possible fix, I'm only getting one hurdles after another, this is my first time trying compose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set `height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` to parent Row and set `fillMaxHeight()` for each child.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun RowSameHeight() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Cyan)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .weight(1F),
        ) {
            Column {
                Text("Battery Percentage")
                Box(Modifier.height(200.dp))
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(Color.Red)
                .weight(1F),
        ) {
            Text("Battery Health")
        }
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(Color.Green)
                .weight(1F),
            text = "AAAAA",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            maxLines = 1,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: let me check if this works

Comment: This one worked